# 本番環境で運用している既存のApacheを削除せずに最新のApacheにアップデートする方法を教えてください。

Tags: linux, centos, apache, yum

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

既存のApacheを削除せずに最新のApacheをアップデートする方法を教えてください。

### 【質問の補足】

#### 1.

現在、自分が運営しているサイトの1つにはWebサーバーとしてApache2.4.6を使っています。
ネットワークのプロトコルをHTTP/1.1からHTTP/2に変更したいと考えていますので、iusレポジトリを使ってApacheのバージョンを最新にしたいと考えています。

#### 2.

現在、サイトで使用しているサーバーの環境は以下のとおりです。サーバーはさくらインターネットの「さくらのVPS」を使用しています。

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 

$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov  5 2018 01:47:09

$ yum list epel-release
...
epel-release.noarch         7-11            @epel
```

#### 3.

実際に実行したコマンドとその結果は以下のとおりです

```
# yum -y install "https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm"
...
インストール中          : ius-release-2-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                         1/1 
  検証中                  : ius-release-2-1.el7.ius.noarch                                                         1/1 

インストール:
  ius-release.noarch 0:2-1.el7.ius                                                                                     

完了しました!

# rpm -ivh https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

...

--> 衝突を処理しています: httpd24u-tools-2.4.41-1.el7.ius.x86_64 は httpd-tools < 2.4.41-1.el7.ius と衝突しています
--> 衝突を処理しています: httpd24u-2.4.41-1.el7.ius.x86_64 は httpd < 2.4.41-1.el7.ius と衝突しています
--> 衝突を処理しています: 1:httpd24u-mod_ssl-2.4.41-1.el7.ius.x86_64 は mod_ssl < 1:2.4.41-1.el7.ius と衝突しています
--> 衝突を処理しています: httpd24u-devel-2.4.41-1.el7.ius.x86_64 は httpd-devel < 2.4.41-1.el7.ius と衝突しています
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。
エラー: httpd24u-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.4.6-88.el7.centos.x86_64
エラー: httpd24u-devel conflicts with httpd-devel-2.4.6-88.el7.centos.x86_64
エラー: httpd24u-mod_ssl conflicts with 1:mod_ssl-2.4.6-88.el7.centos.x86_64
エラー: httpd24u conflicts with httpd-2.4.6-88.el7.centos.x86_64
 問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができます。
 これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

2つめのコマンドである`rpm -ivh https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm`を実行するとエラーが表示されます。

#### 3.

下記のブログを読むと衝突を回避するために下記のコマンドを実行する必要があると書かれています。

```
# yum remove httpd
```

https://note.com/yadoyan/n/n84b4d2c336f3
https://www.rem-system.com/httpd-ius-install/

#### 4.

ですがApacheを更新したいとサーバーはWordPressサイトの本番環境として使っていて、PHPのアンイストールなどの作業はしたくないと考えています。いわゆる「上書き」のような感じでApacheを更新したいと考えています。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: "実際に実行したコマンド" の1つ目と2つ目はどちらも IUS のリポジトリ設定をインストールするものですが、後者は写し間違えでしょうか？ (このコマンドを実行しても続くコンフリクトのエラーにはならないはず)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUS リポジトリで提供されている httpd は base リポジトリのパッケージと競合するように設定されているので上書きインストールはできません。

- [httpd24u-2.4.39-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64/httpd24u-2.4.39-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html)

  rpm の仕組みとして、**Conflicts** の項目で 古いバージョンインストールされている場合は競合を起こすようになっている。
- [httpd-2.4.6-90.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/httpd-2.4.6-90.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm.html)

  base リポジトリのパッケージは特に Conflicts は指定されていない。

---

今回のケースであれば

- (必要に応じて) 既存環境の設定等をバックアップ
- 既存の httpd を停止、アンインストール
- IUS から httpd24u のインストール

という手順を踏むしかないでしょう。

Comment: cubickさん。コメントありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。今後ともよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

teratailで同じ質問をしました。質問に対する結論としては「上書きのようなことはおそらくできない」ということでした。下記のリンクをクリックすると回答をいただいた方のコメントを確認することができます。

https://teratail.com/questions/235075#reply-342151